# HttpContext Cookie

Tags: c#, asp.net

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies.AllKeys.Contains("myCookie") &&
    !String.IsNullOrEmpty(HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["myCookie"].Value))
{
    HttpCookie myCookie = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
}
```

Is there something wrong with this code?  Every once in a while, our production website will get a null reference exception on line 4.   I can't reproduce this in test.

Answer (score 11):

Are you sure you're seeing the exception on Line 4 and not the first line?  Your code looks fine with one exception: `HttpContext.Current` is sometimes `null`, which should cause an exception on your first line of code.

The most common case you'll see this is when you're running code inside a background thread different from the thread that your request is executing on. For example, if you create a thread yourself, or if you execute code in a callback passed into a BeginXXX asynchronous method call, you'll get a null `HttpContext.Current`.

This happens because `HttpContext.Current` is associated with the thread that the request is currently executing on. On a different thread, the framework has no way to know which request you want to use.

There are ways to fix this-- for example .NET's `BackgroundWorker` can propagate context to another thread.  The Asynchronous Pages support in ASP.NET will also propagate context correctly.

So you have two options: either rewrite all your async code to use context-passing async mechanisms like `BackgroundWorker` or Async Pages, or change your code to check for `HttpContext.Current==null` before trying to access any properties of `HttpContext.Current`.

Comment: Yes, it's line 4 that is throwing the exception.